# how to search for every word in the search query using PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am using PHP and mysqli for fetching records from my database .
TABLE engine = `innoDB`.
MYSQL v5.5
Suppose i have this records

1  | Beautiful Switzerland girl |
2  | Beautiful rabbit in park |
3  | Natural sea |

Now if the search query is `Beautiful` it will return first 2 records but the problem is if i searched for `Beautiful anything` , it will return nothing but i want those first 2 records to be displayed in this case because it has the word `beautiful` in it. I am using `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%value%' ORDER BY id ASC` as the mysql query for searching right now .

Is there any other query or method to achieve this or the only possible option is to develop a custom algorithm .

Comment: it would be appreciated if you can paste full query to give resolution to the problem u r facing

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%Beautiful%' OR name LIKE '%anything%'
```

It's the `OR` you have to use. So suppose you get a query from somewhere:

```
// get your query
$query = <...somewhere....>
// explode into words
$words = explode(' ',$query); 
// write conditions, pay attention to security!
foreach ($words as $word)
{
  $escaped = ESCAPE($word); // depends the db extension you use
  $conditions[] = "name LIKE '%$escaped%'";
}
// combine into sql
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".implode(' OR ',$conditions);
```

And then you `OR` all the words in the query.

Comment: i don't know the search query. It will be dynamic .i have just given a example for better understanding.

Comment: So did I, mine is also just an example. Did you understand the `OR` bit?

Comment: o yes but for this i would have to make a custom algorithm to first  explode the sentence then count total words and then accordingly make a query.I mean i was searching for a more efficient way to do that .

Comment: Personally I prefer query builders for this, like the one in Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

Comment: Yes i know this already .Infact can also enhance the algorithm by removing any obvious words like this,that,in,on,etc. BUT what i was trying to know was , can v solve the problem without having to make a custom algorithm .

Comment: No, you need to use algorithms to make a computer do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Full-Text Searches` for this purpose. It will full fill your requirement for more details about full text search you can go through with this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/full-text-search-using-mysql-full-text-search-capabilities/

if you are using `innodb` instead of `myisam` engine than try to go through with this link also

http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/07/08/fine-tuning-mysql-full-text-search-with-innodb/

Comment: I tried that but found that the engine needs to be set to `MYISAM` and the problem is `MYISAM` doesn't allow foreign keys.

Comment: ah, you are using innodb?

Comment: go through with this link http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/07/08/fine-tuning-mysql-full-text-search-with-innodb/

Comment: when i try to use that query on my innoDB table it throws `errorno.:1214 The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Lucene or Solr for full text searching functionality. This will give you very fast data comparatively direct database query.

Reference links : 
http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/lucene/ 
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-lucene-to-index-and-search-text-files.html